# Convert String into Phonetic alphabet in swift

Tags: ios, string, swift3

I want to write a function to convert a `String` into `Phonetic Alphabets`

For instance: 
"Hello World"

Should print:

(Hotel Echo Lima Lima Oscar Whiskey Oscar Romeo Lima Delta).

This is what I have done so far. But Xcode gives me an error

> Usage of unresolved identifier reduce

and

> Usage of unresolved identifier join

Anyone can help me with this as I am new to swift.

```
func catSomes<A>(xs:[A?]) -> [A] {
    return reduce(xs, []) { acc, x in
        x.map { acc + [$0] } ?? acc
    }
}
let letters =  [
        "A" : "Alpha",  "B" : "Bravo",   "C" : "Charlie",
        "D" : "Delta",  "E" : "Echo",    "F" : "Foxtrot",
        "G" : "Golf",   "H" : "Hotel",   "I" : "India",
        "J" : "Juliett","K" : "Kilo",    "L" : "Lima",
        "M" : "Mike",   "N" : "November","O" : "Oscar",
        "P" : "Papa",   "Q" : "Quebec",  "R" : "Romeo",
        "S" : "Sierra", "T" : "Tango",   "U" : "Uniform",
        "V" : "Victor", "W" : "Whiskey", "X" : "X-ray",
        "Y" : "Yankee", "Z" : "Zulu"]
func nato(str:String) -> String {
    return join(" ", catSomes(map(str) { letters[String($0).uppercaseString] }))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
func nato(str:String) -> String {
        var newString = ""
        for c in str.characters {
            c == " " ? newString.append("") : newString.append(letters[String(c).uppercased()]! + " ")
        }
        return newString
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul27_8. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @AtplMohali It will add extra `Space` after last word batter to use `joined`

Comment: check for last char as space after iteration and trim it.

Answer (score 0):

To get your expected output this should be enough

```
func nato(str:String) -> String {
    return str.characters.map{ letters["\($0)".uppercased()] ?? "" }.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

I did not understand the use of your `catSomes` method.